Unable to increase max number of open files per-process in 22.04
Despite my best efforts, I have been unable to increase the maximum number of open files per-process.
Here's what I have done:
/etc/systemd/user.conf:
DefaultLimitNOFILE=20000500

/etc/systemd/system.conf:
DefaultLimitNOFILE=20000500

/etc/security/limits.conf:
* soft nofile 20000500
* hard nofile 20000500

/etc/pam.d/common-session:
...
session required        pam_limits.so

/etc/pam.d/common-session-noninteractive:
...
session required        pam_limits.so

/etc/sysctl.conf:
fs.inotify.max_user_watches=52428800
fs.file-max=25000500
fs.nr_open=20000500

With all of this in place, I have a python script that I am using to test. The goal behind this script is to try and open 1048577 files and see if it fails, given that my ulimit -Hn reports a value of 1048576.
import os

def test_open_file_descriptors(num_files):
    fds = []
    try:
        for i in range(num_files):
            fd = os.open("/etc/passwd", os.O_RDONLY)
            fds.append(fd)
            if i % 1000 == 0:
                print(f"Opened {i} files")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error encountered. Failed to open i={i}: {e}")
    finally:
        for fd in fds:
            os.close(fd)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    num_files = 1048577  # 1,048,577 files
    test_open_file_descriptors(num_files)

No matter what I do, the program fails after printing out that it was able to open 1048000 files.
...
Opened 1047000 files
Opened 1048000 files
Error encountered. Failed to open i=1048573: [Errno 24] Too many open files: '/etc/passwd'

What am I missing? Why can't I seem to be able to open more files than 1048576? What does one have to do to increase this limit to, say, 10,000,000?

Please edit your question and edit your code and remove the wrong error handling (never use an except clause which catches any type of exception globally) and add the full stack trace of the error message you get from Python.

Partially done. The goal of the script was just to get a sense of how many files the process was able to open before it fails, and it does succeed at that.

Part 1: answering the question (before the question was edited) about only getting 1048573 files when the limit is 1048576?:
While ulimit -Hn might say 1048576, there will be a couple of overhead file handles also related to the process.
For this example, and so I would have time to poke around, I inserted a sleep in your program before closing the files and exiting:
...
finally:
    time.sleep(int(300))
    for fd in fds:
        ...

And I get the same as you:
...
Opened 1047000 files
Opened 1048000 files
Error encountered. Failed to open i=1048573: [Errno 24] Too many open files: '/etc/passwd'

But their are overhead file handles and such:
doug@s19:~$ ls -l /proc/1449/fd | grep passwd | wc -l
1048573
doug@s19:~$ ls -l /proc/1449/fd | grep -v passwd | wc -l
4
doug@s19:~$ ls -l /proc/1449/fd | grep total | wc -l
1
doug@s19:~$ ls -l /proc/1449/fd | head
total 0
lrwx------ 1 doug doug 64 Apr 19 16:27 0 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 doug doug 64 Apr 19 16:27 1 -> /dev/pts/0
lr-x------ 1 doug doug 64 Apr 19 16:27 10 -> /etc/passwd
lr-x------ 1 doug doug 64 Apr 19 16:27 100 -> /etc/passwd
lr-x------ 1 doug doug 64 Apr 19 16:27 1000 -> /etc/passwd
lr-x------ 1 doug doug 64 Apr 19 16:27 10000 -> /etc/passwd
lr-x------ 1 doug doug 64 Apr 19 16:27 100000 -> /etc/passwd
lr-x------ 1 doug doug 64 Apr 19 16:27 1000000 -> /etc/passwd
lr-x------ 1 doug doug 64 Apr 19 16:27 1000001 -> /etc/passwd
doug@s19:~$ cat /proc/sys/fs/nr_open
1048576
doug@s19:~$ ulimit -Sn
1048576
doug@s19:~$ ulimit -Hn
1048576
... EDIT: added later, hence different PID ...
doug@s19:~$ ls -l /proc/1649/fd | grep -v total | grep -v passwd
lrwx------ 1 doug doug 64 Apr 19 17:30 0 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 doug doug 64 Apr 19 17:30 1 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 doug doug 64 Apr 19 17:30 2 -> /dev/pts/0

I was not able to set my ulimits higher than 1048576, but I could write a larger number to /proc/sys/fs/nr_open
Part 2: Answering the question: What does one have to do to increase this limit to, say, 10,000,000?
The default kernel compile time open file limit is defined as fs/file.c:unsigned int sysctl_nr_open __read_mostly = 1024*1024; and boot time limits will be restricted to that limit, as you have discovered. So the short answer to the question for regular users is that you can't.
The longer answer, for root users is to change the post boot values:
root@s19:/media/nvme/home/doug/csv-plot/tmp# echo 16777216 > /proc/sys/fs/nr_open
root@s19:/media/nvme/home/doug/csv-plot/tmp# ulimit -H -n 16777216
root@s19:/media/nvme/home/doug/csv-plot/tmp# ulimit -S -n 16777216

Having done that, I changed your program to ask for 15 million files to be opened and ran it from the same root session:
...
Opened 14994000 files
Opened 14995000 files
Opened 14996000 files
Opened 14997000 files
Opened 14998000 files
Opened 14999000 files

I could not do it as a regular user and the ulimit settings also got lost between root user sessions.

So basically stdout, stdin and stderr... makes sense

Sorry, I'm a bit confused. I understand that you are pointing out the extra, base file descriptors of 0, 1, 2 (stdin, stdout, stderr), but that doesn't help answer the core question of how to go about increasing this limit past 1048576.

In your original question, before your edits, you had two questions. I answered one of them.
